# Post undeleted and converted to comment still shows as being deleted from review

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, deleted-answers, convert-to-comment

I found [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/151810/31394) (only visible to 10k+ users on SFF, sorry) which had been deleted from review some hours ago but also flagged for conversion to a comment. I undeleted it and converted it to a comment (which of course re-deletes the answer), only to see that the post claimed to have been "deleted *from review* just now" by the same list of users as before.

Here's a screenshot of the timeline:

[image: timeline]

And here's one of what the post itself looks like now:

[image: post]

It was actually deleted from review 3 hours ago and then undeleted and redeleted by me 36 minutes ago, but to a casual observer it looks like it was deleted from review 36 minutes ago.

*I'm posting this as a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) report because it's* technically *showing incorrect information, but I'd be perfectly happy to be told it's actually a new feature. In fact, I've often found it annoying that when a whole bunch of users have voted to delete a post and then I convert it to a comment, their votes don't show up and it looks like I've acted unilaterally to remove it. This kind of remedies that.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Better late than never... a fix for this went out earlier this week. Deleted answers now show the users involved in the most recent deletion if the post was undeleted and deleted again since the original review.

Comment: Definitely better late than never: I remember running into this issue again just recently. Thanks!