# Mod deletion after a review deletion is attributed incorrectly

Tags: bug, review, deleted-answers

I just deleted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656144/android-immortal-service/43124871#43124871) in response to a disputed review flag:

[image]

After seeing the deleted-by label, I assumed that review had somehow beaten me to the deletion. [The timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43124871/timeline) disproves that:

[image]

It looks like the deletion label on the post is picking up on the later timestamp, but the earlier deleters. Looks like a bug.

Comment: Related (possible duplicate): [Post undeleted and converted to comment still shows as being deleted from review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290623/278659)